# Cannot create PID file

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, agent

after a restart of the zabbix agent cannot be started again. I checked the logfile:
Code:

```
2021/07/19 11:39:03.032565 Starting Zabbix Agent 2 (5.2.7)
2021/07/19 11:39:03.033020 OpenSSL library (OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020) initialized
2021/07/19 11:39:03.033058 cannot initialize PID file: cannot open PID file [/run/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.pid]: open /run/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.pid: no such file or directory
```

I have no idea why the pid file can't be created anymore

Anyone?

Thanks,

DexDy

Comment: `/run/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.pid: no such file or directory` Create the directory and give access.

Answer (score 0):

The Zabbix installation package creates a systemv unit that looks for the pidfile in `/var/run`. The same package writes the pidfile in `/tmp` by default (see [zabbix_agentd](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_agentd)). SystemV will of course kill the agent because it doesn't find the pidfile.

Checklist:

- did you change the default agent configuration to write the PidFile in /var/run, or is it still writing to the default folder /tmp?
- is selinux enforced? selinux will prevent the agent from working if you don't configure its policy

Answer (score 0):

During install zabbix-agent creating folder /run/zabbix/. When zabbix agent starts PID file automatically creates in this folder.
You may follow next steps to diagnostic and resolve problem:

1. Reinstall zabbix-agent.
2. In config file **/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf** change directory for PID file in parameter "PidFile". Then start zabbix-agent